# Atom: Disable auto-formatting on save

Tags: atom-editor

I have a project I started with Sublime and/or WebStorm, and now I want to switch to Atom.

The problem is whenever I save, the whole file gets reformatted and that is a big mess for git, which shows mostly all lines being modified.

I want to disable auto-format on save. Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) package installed, you can enable/disable auto-format on save for each supported language separately:

`Preferences` → `Packages` → `atom-beautify` → scroll waaay down to `Language Config - LangXYZ - Beautify On Save` (with LangXYZ being the language configured).

---

If you don't have extra packages installed, it might the [whitespace](https://atom.io/packages/whitespace) package, which comes with Atom and is enabled by default: `Preferences` → `Packages` → `whitespace`

You can either click `Disable` and be done with it (I did :-)), or you can disable the package selectively via entries in your `config.cson` file, as documented on the package page itself.

Answer (score 4):

"By default, JSFormat's Format on save is set to true."

If you install the JSFormat, you can disable or remove it.

With Atom  v1.6.1, I remove JSFormat, and it won't auto format when saving JavaScript files.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Atom cleans up the whitespaces when you save a file.

To prevent this default behavior, you have to follow these steps:

- Go to `Preferences ...` (Command + ',' in macOS)
- Click on `Open Config Folder`
- Open `config.cson`
- Append the following lines to the bottom of it:

`whitespace:
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false`

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>
2. Type "Application Open your Config" , hit enter
3. Paste

`"whitespace":
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false`

[image]